# Truck rental, Mexico pick-up, U.S. drop-off

Tags: usa, car-rentals, mexico

So my car recently died here in Mexico, and I need to tow it back to the U.S. to have it worked on.  (It's a [long story](http://forums.tdiclub.com/showthread.php?t=333861)).  I'm hoping I might be able to rent a small (u-haul style, would be fine, or any vehicle capable of towing a small car) truck and car dolly in Guadalajara, and return it in Austin, Texas.

Is there any chance of this?

Comment: It might well work out easier to use a different truck on each side of the border. I don't envy you.

Comment: @hippietrail: Yeah.  That's an option.  Although it probably requires crossing the border at least 3 times, to get both trucks and my car in the same place at the same time.  That will probably take all day...

Comment: Another alternative would be to get a company to take it for you. Less trouble but more money I'd say. There's your trade-off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nafta has long allowed Mexican trucks to go 50 miles into Texas, and recently they have successfully sued to be able to operate in the US. That said, only one shipping company currently operates as such, and I don't remember it's name.

Still, even with that 50 miles, you might be able to cross into TX , drop the trailer, and return to Mexico for your drop off, then arrange for Enterprise to "pick you up. " I suspect if you tell the guards what you're doing, you can probably cross.

If nothing else, there's the impound lot where customs can hold your trailer until you can get the new vehicle in the US.